# Safari transform rotatex bug

Tags: html, css, safari, css-transforms

I have a weird bug with safari...

I have 3 divs with captions, which are hidden with `rotateX(-91deg)`. On `:hover` the caption comes down via `rotateX(0deg)`. It works perfectly in Chrome etc. When i hover in safari it works only on the first div. When i hover on the 2. or the 3. the animation doesn't work.

Check out my demo: http://jsbin.com/aseced/28/edit

HTML:

```
<article class="tile2x1">
  <section class="caption"></section>
</article>
<article class="tile2x1">   
  <section class="caption"></section>
</article>
<article class="tile2x1">
  <section class="caption"></section>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
[class*="tile"] > section.caption {
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px;

    transform-origin: top;
    -o-transform-origin: top;
    -moz-transform-origin: top;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;

    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateX( -91deg );
    -o-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateX( -91deg );
    -moz-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateX( -91deg );
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateX( -91deg );

    transition: all .25s linear;
    -o-transition: all .25s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .25s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s linear;

    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Chrome and Safari */
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Firefox */
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Internet Explorer */
}

[class*="tile"]:hover > section.caption {
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateX( 0deg );
    -o-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateX( 0deg );
    -moz-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateX( 0deg );
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateX( 0deg );
}
```

Thanks for any help.

TJL

Comment: I don't use safari, but have you tried to mitigate the bug by ... using 90 deg instead of 91, removing the backface-visibility:hidden, maybe using visibility:hidden and in the hover visibility:visible insetad? Or perhaps its an issue with attribute selector + hover, try using class selector with the :hover instead.

Comment: i've updated the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/aseced/29/edit) with your suggestions. But still not working...

Comment: @LastCoder do you have any idea?

Comment: How about -- .tile2x1:hover .caption { ... } --

Comment: @LastCoder if i remove `position: relative` from the parent element it works. But i need this attribute to positioning the `.caption`. Any idea how to solve this?